# JAVA Get text from String

Tags: java, string

Hi I get this String from server :

```
id_not="autoincrement"; id_obj="-"; id_tr="-"; id_pgo="-"; typ_not=""; tresc="Nie wystawił"; datetime="-"; lon="-"; lat="-";
```

I need to create a new String e.x String word and send a value which I get from String `tresc="Nie wystawił"`

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  What is "e.x"?

Comment: return json from server

Comment: Who upvotes such unclear question?

Comment: @SteveSmith it shuld be e.g

Comment: Krzysztof Your voting ring acts too obvious. Step down a bit.

Comment: You could try a regex on that String=

Comment: @Jan how this regex look like ?

Comment: something like Pattern.compile("tresc=\"([^\"]+)\"); and then fetch group(1) from the Matcher if you can find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Jan suggest in comment you can use regex for example :

```
String str = "id_not=\"autoincrement\"; id_obj=\"-\"; id_tr=\"-\"; id_pgo=\"-\"; typ_not=\"\"; tresc=\"Nie wystawił\"; datetime=\"-\"; lon=\"-\"; lat=\"-\";";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("tresc(.*?);");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
tresc="Nie wystawił";
```

---

If you want to get only the value of `tresc` you can use :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("tresc=\"(.*?)\";");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
Nie wystawił
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("tresc=\"([^\"]+)\");
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringFromServer);
if(m.find()) {
  String whatYouWereLookingfor = m.group(1);
}
```

should to the trick. JSON parsing might be much better in the long run if you need additional values

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but i think you get a string from server and from that string you want the string/value for **tresc**. You can first search for tresc in the string you get. like:

```
serverString.substring(serverString.indexOf("tresc") + x , serverString.length());
```

Here replace x with 'how much further you want to pick characters.

Read on **substring** and **`delimiters`**

As values are separated by semicolon so annother solution could be:

```
int delimiter = serverstring.indexOf(";"); 
//in string thus giving you the index of where it is in the string
```

// Now delimiter can be -1, if lets say the string had no ";" at all in it i.e. no ";" is not found. 
//check and account for it.

```
if (delimiter != -1) 
String subString= serverstring.substring(5 , iend);
```

Here 5 means tresc is on number five in string, so it will five you tresc part.

You can then use it anyway you want.